# Change the format of dictionary object in pandas

Tags: python

Apologies for any formatting errors as I started using stackoverflow recently . I have few records in my json output being displayed on a browser in the following format generated by my Python code using an API:

Current format:

```
[{"individual_id":"abcd1234","start_time":"2022-03-01 10:08:00","end_time":"2022-03-01 10:12:00","duration_minutes":4.0,"event_name":"activity","source":"Ple;fitbit;fitbit","parameters":["{'duration': 68.0, 'caloriesBurned': 15, 'activityName': 'Run', 'distance': 0, 'distanceUnit': 'Kilometer', 'activityLevel': [{'minutes': 0, 'name': 'sedentary'}, {'minutes': 0, 'name': 'lightly'}, {'minutes': 0, 'name': 'fairly'}, {'minutes': 0, 'name': 'very'}]}","{'duration': 68.0, 'caloriesBurned': 8, 'activityName': 'Run', 'distance': 0, 'distanceUnit': 'Kilometer', 'activityLevel': [{'minutes': 0, 'name': 'sedentary'}, {'minutes': 0, 'name': 'lightly'}, {'minutes': 0, 'name': 'fairly'}, {'minutes': 0, 'name': 'very'}]}"]}
```

Expected format:

```
{'individual_id':'abcd1234','start_time':'2022-03-01 10:08:00',
'end_time':'2022-03-01 10:12:00','duration_minutes':4.0,'event_name':'activity',
'source':'Ple;fitbit;fitbit',
'parameters':{'param1':{'duration': 68.0, 
'caloriesBurned': 15, 'activityName': 'Run', 'distance': 0, 'distanceUnit': 'Kilometer',
 'activityLevel': {'minutes': 0, 'name': 'sedentary'}, {'minutes': 0, 'name': 'lightly'},
 {'minutes': 0, 'name': 'fairly'}, {'minutes': 0, 'name': 'very'}},'param2':{'duration': 68.0,
 'caloriesBurned': 8, 'activityName': 'Run', 'distance': 0, 'distanceUnit': 'Kilometer',
 'activityLevel': [{'minutes': 0, 'name': 'sedentary'}, {'minutes': 0, 'name': 'lightly'},
 {'minutes': 0, 'name': 'fairly'}, {'minutes': 0, 'name': 'very'}},
 'totalcaloriesburned':23,
 'totalduration':240000
 }
 }
```

Please note that not all rows have calories keys in the parameters column. If they are present compute the "totalcaloriesburned" else we just leave it.

Comment: Syntax of **Current format** and **Expected format** at the code are invalid json formats.

Comment: What would you suggest?

Comment: Can you explain the rationale behind the expected format? For example, after 'parameters' you want to add 'param1', but there's not 'param2' later. Also, how is this related to pandas?

Comment: Hi! So within the parameters whenever we encounter a 'duration' keyw it is start of a new param. Say suppose we have 3 durations within parameters they need to be separated by param1, param2 and param3 keys. This should increment automatically as well

Comment: Step 1 is not to worry about JSON yet.  You have dictionaries and nested lists.  Construct your Python dictionary the way you want it, then the JSON code will automatically put it in the right format.